# 5.16 Remarks from baby Rudin

Tags: real-analysis

[image]

How Rudin got expression $(29)$? I think so: If $f(t)=f_1(t)+if_2(t)$ then $$f'(x)=\lim_{t\to x}\dfrac{f(t)-f(x)}{t-x}=\lim_{t\to x}\dfrac{f_1(t)-f_1(x)}{t-x}+i\lim_{t\to x}\dfrac{f_2(t)-f_2(x)}{t-x}=f_1'(x)+if_2'(x).$$I think that it's not correct because we don't know does these limits exists?

Can anyone explain this moment please?

Comment: What about the sentence below the red line? And please, call it "Rudin's Principles" or something else than "Baby Rudin". It does not sound fair.

Comment: "Baby Rudin" is a term of endearment; it's fine.

Comment: @mickep, so expression (29) is true with that below sentence, right? Sorry. English not my native language and sometimes I have troubles with it.

Comment: But Baby should be capitalized, @zhw. :)

Comment: To the question, the limits exist because we already know the derivatives exist.

Comment: @Paul, Does this mention in a book? He only wrote that $f'(x)=f'_1(x)+if'_2(x)$. How he gow that I can't understand :(

Comment: @RFZ, it says "if and only if $f_1$ and $f_2$ are differentiable at $x$."

Comment: @Paul, can you check my proof below please?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $f:[a,b]\to \mathbb{C}$ is a complex function. Then $f(t)=f_1(t)+if_2(t)$ for $t\in [a,b]$ where $f_1, f_2$ are the real.

**Theorem:** $f$ is differentiable at $x$ **iff** both $f_1$ and $f_2$ are differentiable at $x$.

**Proof:**
$\Leftarrow$ If both $f_1$ and $f_2$ are differentiable at $x$. Then exists limits $\lim \limits_{t\to x}\dfrac{f_i(t)-f_i(x)}{t-x}=f'_i(x)$ for $i=1,2$. Summing these we get: $$\lim \limits_{t\to x}\dfrac{f(t)-f(x)}{t-x}=f'_1(x)+if'_2(x).$$ So $f'(x)=f'_1(x)+if'_2(x).$

$\Rightarrow$ Let $f$ is differentiable at $x$. Then exists limit $$f'(x)=\lim \limits_{t\to x}\dfrac{f(t)-f(x)}{t-x}=\lim \limits_{t\to x}\left [\dfrac{f_1(t)-f_1(x)}{t-x}+i\dfrac{f_2(t)-f_2(x)}{t-x}\right].$$ Let $\operatorname{Re}f'(x)=u(x)$ and $\operatorname{Im}f'(x)=v(x)$. From inequality: $$0\leqslant \left|\dfrac{f_1(t)-f_1(x)}{t-x}-u(x)\right|\leqslant \left|\dfrac{f(t)-f(x)}{t-x}-f'(x) \right|$$ we get that $u(x)=f'_1(x)$ and also $v(x)=f'_2(x)$. Q.E.D.

Comment: Hi, I have a question about the first part of your proof. Is that mean we can take "i" out of the limit symbol? It seems that Rudin didn't mention it.

Answer (score 2):

Just to have an answer to this question, so that it can be marked as completed.

It would perhaps have been clearer to write:

> The function $f$ is differentiable at $x$ if and only if the functions $f_1$ and $f_2$ are differentiable at $x$. In case all of them are differentiable, 
>   $$f'(x)=f_1'(x)+f_2'(x).
> $$

Comment: Dear mickep! I wrote the proof of that fact below. Can you look at this please?